Selenium - SessionNotCreated could not start a new session. possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure
I am facing this error while integrating the selenium with docker and azure pipeline.

SessionNotCreated could not start a new session. possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-notifications], extensions: []}}]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-notifications], extensions: []}}
[ERROR]   SampleRun.setup:68 » SessionNotCreated Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'fv-az369-95', ip: '10.1.0.4'
Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.5.0-1018-azure', java.version: '11.0.22'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 4
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  47.179 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-25T02:15:53Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.2.5:test (default-test) on project DTest: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/vsts/work/1/s/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/usr/bin/bash'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/bash'
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;source=TaskInternal;]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]
Finishing: Maven clean install

Azure-pipeline.yml:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  
variables:
  java.version: '16'

jobs:
- job: 'Setup'
  displayName: 'Setup Environment'
  steps:
  - script: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-$(java.version)-jdk
      echo "Java version:"
      java -version
    displayName: 'Set up Java'

  - script: |
      sudo apt-get remove containerd
    displayName: 'Remove conflicting packages'

  - script: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
      curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
      echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
    displayName: 'Install Docker from official repository'

  - script: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y maven
      mvn -version
    displayName: 'Install Maven'

  - script: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y unzip
      wget https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/4.18/selenium-java-4.18.1.zip
      unzip selenium-java-4.18.1.zip -d selenium-java
      cp selenium-java/libs/* .
      rm -rf selenium-java selenium-java-4.18.1.zip
    displayName: 'Install Selenium Java dependencies'

- job: 'Docker'
  displayName: 'Run Docker Containers'
  dependsOn: Setup
  steps:
  - script: |
      docker run -d -p 4442:4442 -p 4443:4443 --shm-size=2g \
        -e SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub \
        -e SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442 \
        -e SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443 \
        -e VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1 \
        -e SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=2 \
        --name chrome selenium/node-chrome:4.18.1-20240224
    displayName: 'Run Chrome Node Docker container'

  - script: |
      docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 4445:4445 --shm-size=2g \
        -e SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub \
        -e SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4444 \
        -e SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4445 \
        -e VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1 \
        -e SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=2 \
        --name edge selenium/node-edge:4.18.1-20240224
    displayName: 'Run Edge Node Docker container'

  - script: |
      docker run -d -p 4446:4446 -p 4447:4447 -p 4448:4448 \
        --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:4.18.1-20240224
    displayName: 'Run Selenium Hub Docker container'

- job: 'Tests'
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  dependsOn: Docker
  steps:
  - script: |
      mvn clean install
    displayName: 'Maven clean install'

  - script: |
      mvn test
    displayName: 'Run Selenium tests'

Main Selenium file:
public class SampleRun {
    

    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driverThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driverThreadLocal.get();
    }

    public void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        driverThreadLocal.set(driver);
    }

    public void quitDriver() {
        WebDriver driver = driverThreadLocal.get();
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
            driverThreadLocal.remove();
        }
    }

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    public void setup(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {

        URL hubUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");

        switch (browser.toLowerCase()) {
        case "chrome":
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications"); // Disable browser notifications
            chromeOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true); // Accept insecure certificates
            setDriver(new RemoteWebDriver(hubUrl, chromeOptions));
            break;
        case "edge":
            EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
            edgeOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
            setDriver(new RemoteWebDriver(hubUrl, edgeOptions));
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid browser: " + browser);
        }

        if (getDriver() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("WebDriver is not initialized properly.");
        }

        System.out.println("WebDriver initialized for " + browser);
    }

    @Test
    public void testScenario1() throws InterruptedException {
        getDriver().get("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Page title: " + getDriver().getTitle());
    }

    @Test
    public void testScenario2() throws InterruptedException {
        getDriver().get("https://www.facebook.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Page title: " + getDriver().getTitle());
    }

    @Test
    public void testScenario3() throws InterruptedException {
        getDriver().get("https://www.reddit.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Page title: " + getDriver().getTitle());
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        quitDriver();
    }
}

Kindly let me know if anything needs to be changed.


What's the result if you run the same scripts locally to start a docker container and run Selenium test inside it? 2. In which task you get the above error. 3. Please enable verbose log and share the detailed error message.


possibly wrong port?  Your docker: docker run -d -p 4446:4446 -p 4447:4447 -p 4448:4448  Your hubURL: http://localhost:4444

@browsermator It is not wrong port , i have already fixed that issue.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT - It works fine locally if i ran alone with docker or azure pipeline but by the time when i integrated both azure pipeline and docker, I got the above error during the 'maven clean install'

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT - I have enabled verbose log, below error is what i got --> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.2.5:test (default-test) on project DTest: There are test failures. ##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/usr/bin/bash'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/bash'
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;source=TaskInternal;]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]

According to the official doc Agent pool jobs,

When using Microsoft-hosted agents, each job in a pipeline gets a fresh agent.

For your "Tests" job, it's running on a brand-new ubuntu-latest agent instead of your docker container set up in "Docker" job. Try to run the steps in one job.
